# php ezpdf new line in eztable

Tags: php, newline, ezpdf

How can i add a new line in eztable cell text?
I tried that I change \n to \n\r but it isn't works.

Maybe that the orignal ezpdf eztable works, because may someone made modified of this.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you use single quote (') while setting up a new line for the text.
You should try replacing the single quote (') with the double one (")  when using \n.
It worked for me.